# How do you remove dd-wrt and restore to factory firmware on a Dlink DIR-868L?

Tags: firmware

I tried uploading the factory firmware through the dd-wrt firmware upgrade interface but it keeps on failing to overwrite it. How do I restore my router to factory firmware?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Plug the Ethernet cable that connects your computer, that was plugged into one of the LAN ports,
> 2. Setup your PC with static IP - ex: 192.168.0.2 (different from 192.168.0.1)
> 3. Make sure the PC has the new firmware
> 4. Unplug the power
> 5. Hold the reset button for 3~5 seconds and re plug the power WITHOUT RELEASING THE RESET BUTTON.
>      6.Open a web browser to 192.168.0.1 and then you should see EMERGENCY FLASHING page then click browse/upload locate the file and click UPLOAD FIRMWARE NOW
> 6. You should see a SUCCSESS page, If you don’t then re do steps 2-6

*You need to hold the reset button in until the amber power light keeps blinking on and off*

[source](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=44909.0)

You can download the latest firmware here: http://support.dlink.com/productinfo.aspx?m=dir-868l